# apache2 proxypass hangs

Tags: apache-2.2, proxypass

We have apache2 proxy server at front end and running couple of application servers at backend, one of the buggy app server hangs and reboots, which takes 2-4 minutes, during this time all of other apps servers hangs as well, as they go through same proxy server.

Here below is the Apache proxy config:

```
ProxyPass        /app1 http://backend1:8080/ 
ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://backend1:8080/ 

ProxyPass        /app2 http://backend2:8080/ 
ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://backend2:8080/ 


ProxyPass        /app3 http://buggy-backend3:8080/ 
ProxyPassReverse /app3 http://buggy-backend3:8080/
```

Is there any apache directive, which check if backend is not responding should ignore it, and keep serving the others.

Will much appreciate any help.

WA-Mian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use something like haproxy which is designed for exactly this kind of thing. apache mod_proxy_balancer may also do what you need.

EDIT: I suspect the reason apache hangs is that the timeout is set to a relatively large number and apache will be running of child processes which are waiting for the hung app server.

[ProxyTimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout) will give you a way to get apache to timeout a backend quicker.

You could also look at increasing the number of children apache is allowed to spawn and increasing that number.

Comment: Hi Many thanks for reply, They are 3 separate application servers, so we don't need to load balance at the moment.

Comment: ok. Edited with an alternative fix

Comment: Thank you for your help, We did decrease proxy timeout for buggy backend and increased the apache child processes, it did the trick, now our 2 rest of apps servers are ok, when 3rd is even down bit longer.